# Placing a $ in Edit Text but not have it show on Database

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

**What's the best way to achieve a similar result?**

I'm quite new to android development/java etc, so my first part I want to solve is the $ and per hour hint that stays on the right-hand side of the edit text input.

And then I will tackle the boolean yes or no that allows there to be 2 edit text boxes with a min rate and a max rate that will be able to be input into the database. ( if you have any tips or solutions to this would be greatly appreciated)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfntg.jpg)

My Attempt at coding it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MechanicMore.MechanicHourlyRateActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/HourlyText"
        android:layout_width="359dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:text="What is your hourly Rate?"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="356dp"
        android:hint="Per Hour"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/HourlyText">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mechanic_hourlyRate"
            android:layout_width="173dp"
            android:layout_height="86dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:digits="0123456789."
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Per Hour"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: what did you try so far??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a code writing service.

Comment: @ScaryWombat i don't want someone to write the code for me, i want someone to provide me with some help as to how i can achieve my end result.

Comment: @AmitJangid i have posted my code so far, I used TextInputLayout to have the hint rise above the input, but i want it to stay to the right of it possibly. If i didn't have TextInput layout the hint goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rate"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dollarSign"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/_25"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dollarSign"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:text="@string/dollar"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:text="@string/per_hour"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/rate"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```